# Nat type with difference list

Tags: types, ocaml, gadt

I am encoding natural numbers as a difference list:

```
type z = Z
type +'a s = S

type _ nat =
  | Z : ('l * 'l) nat
  | S : ('l * 'm) nat -> ('l * 'm s) nat
```

This allows me to encode addition easily :

```
let rec add : type l m n . (l*m) nat -> (m*n) nat -> (l*n) nat =
  fun i1 i2 ->  match i2 with
    | Z -> i1
    | S i -> S (add i1 i) (* OK *)
```

However the following variant don't typecheck:

```
let rec add2 : type l m n . (l*m) nat -> (m*n) nat -> (l*n) nat =
  fun i1 i2 ->  match i2 with
    | Z -> i1
    | S i -> add2 (S i1) i    (* KO *)
```

Does anybody know how to make it right, i.e. having an efficient typed add, possibly changing the Nat type ?

Note that this question is more general than just the Nat addition: with more complicated sized type, the same question arrise. E.g. with sized list, all the accumlator-based function like rev_append are hard to type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `S i1` has type `(l s * m s) nat` whilst `i` has type `m * n`. The recursive call to `add2` is therefore ill-typed: `add2` expect the rightmost index of its first argument to match the leftmost one of its second and `m s` is most definitely different from `m`.

Because you are encoding a value as a difference, you can easily fix that: you can notice that `(l * m) nat` and `(l s * m s) nat` should be the same thing. And you can indeed define a function `shift` turning one into the other which is basically an identity function:

```
let rec shift : type l m. (l*m) nat -> (l s * m s) nat = function
  | Z   -> Z
  | S i -> S (shift i)
```

You can then adjust the type of `i` in the recursive call to `add2` to have the whole thing typecheck:

```
let rec add2 : type l m n . (l*m) nat -> (m*n) nat -> (l*n) nat =
  fun i1 i2 ->  match i2 with
    | Z -> i1
    | S i -> add2 (S i1) (shift i)
```

Edit: getting rid of the non tail-recursive `shift`.

## Continuation Passing Style Transformation

A common technique to turn a function which is not tail-recursive into a tail recursive one is to define it in [Continuation Passing Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style): the function takes an extra argument which describes what to do with the returned value

We can turn `shift` into a tail-recursive function `shift3` like so:

```
let shift3 : type l m. (l*m) nat -> (l s * m s) nat =
  let rec aux : type l m c. ((l s * m s) nat -> c) -> (l * m) nat -> c =
   fun k i -> match i with
     | Z -> k Z
     | S j -> aux (fun i -> k (S i)) j
  in fun i -> aux (fun x -> x) i
```

Which then lets us define `add3`:

```
let rec add3 : type l m n . (l*m) nat -> (m*n) nat -> (l*n) nat =
  fun i1 i2 ->  match i2 with
    | Z -> i1
    | S i -> add3 (S i1) (shift3 i)
```

## Sledgehammer: Obj.magic

One (easy but dirty) way of getting rid of the non tail-recursive `shift` function is to replace it with `Obj.magic`: indeed, as mentioned before, our `shift`s are nothing but structurally defined identity functions.

This leads us to:

```
let shift4 : type l m. (l*m) nat -> (l s * m s) nat = Obj.magic

let rec add4 : type l m n . (l*m) nat -> (m*n) nat -> (l*n) nat =
  fun i1 i2 ->  match i2 with
    | Z -> i1
    | S i -> add4 (S i1) (shift4 i)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which explain well the typing issue. It is however not very satisfying, as the goal of `add2` was to be tailcall recursive. It is achieved here at the cost of using another non-tailcall recursive function...

Comment: @lavi See my edit: I have added `shift3` which behaves just like `shift` except that it's defined in continuation passing style so that it's recursive, as well as a small paragraph on `Obj.magic`. I'd rather stick to the safe part of the language and use the CPS one though.

Comment: Yes, technically `shift3` is tail recursive. However there is no gain, as stack consumption is the same, with a big growing continuation. So I am still a bit puzzled. Perhapps the good solution is indead to use Obj.magic to encode the difference invariant... But then there is no gain using GADT. Before there were in Ocaml, this kind of stuff was encoded with phantom type, so there were no need of Obj.magic. I would hope GADT to bring me cleaner code, but I am not sure now.